# Dynamic Component Name in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am importing six different dice icons using `react-icons` as follows:

```
import {
  FaDiceOne as DiceOne,
  FaDiceTwo as DiceTwo,
  FaDiceThree as DiceThree,
  FaDiceFour as DiceFour,
  FaDiceFive as DiceFive,
  FaDiceSix as DiceSix,
} from "react-icons/fa";
```

Currently I am using these six components in my `Dice` component as follows:

```
function Dice({num}) {
<div>
 {num === 'one' && <DiceOne />}
 {num === 'two' && <DiceTwo />}
 {num === 'three' && <DiceThree />}
 {num === 'four' && <DiceFour />}
 {num === 'five' && <DiceFive />}
 {num === 'six' && <DiceSix />}
</div>

}

export default Dice
```

This works -- meaning, I can do the following:

```
import Dice from "./Dice";

...

<Dice num="four" />
```

Which would use the `FaDiceFour` icon that I imported from `react-icons`

However, this does not seem to me the ideal situation.  What I would really like to do is make the Component name dynamic.  After all, each and every component has basically the same exact name -- just with a different number.

In essence, what I want is something like this:

```
// Dice.js
const function Dice() {

 <Dice{num} />

}

export default Dice

// other file
import Dice from './Dice'

<Dice num="Four" />
```

Now, I know this does not work, but it is the idea that I am trying to get across.  What I want is a way to use the prop value from the `num` prop and use it to dynamically generate the component name (rather then have to do a number of conditional checks as I currently have it).

What I am wondering is whether or not there is a way to do this with react.  I.e., is there a way to make the component name dynamic depending on the value passed to a prop of that component?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be  destructuring `num` from props in the first Dice function above

Comment: And you're defining your `Dice` as a function expression and you're using `const` at the same time

Comment: @fortunee I wrote the question from memory and thus had some typos.  I do destructure the `num` prop and there is no duplication of both `const` and `function`.  Those were just typos on my part (I updated my question to remove those typos).  The point of my question is whether or not I can replace the six conditional checks of the value of the `num` prop with a single line of code that will render the correct icon component depending on the value passed to the `num` prop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for is a way to make Dice a presentational component that takes in props (ie: `num`) and renders any of those React icons based on the value of `num`:

Your Dice function should look like this.

```js
const Dice = ({ num }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {num === 'one' && <DiceOne />}
      {num === 'two' && <DiceTwo />}
      {num === 'three' && <DiceThree />}
      {num === 'four' && <DiceFour />}
      {num === 'five' && <DiceFive />}
      {num === 'six' && <DiceSix />}
    </>
  )
}

export default Dice; // if it's a different file
```

Use it like this:

```js
<Dice num={num} />
```

See a working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kwg3p9

Comment: Actually, that was just at typo on my part which I just fixed.  I didn't meant to leave `{num}` out of the arguments for the Dice component.  What I am looking to do is replace all of the `num === "x"` arguments with just one line of code that renders the right component depending on which prop is passed.  Imagine that I had a 1000 different options, rather then just six.  I would not want to write 1000 different conditional checks.